# Bound the variation of this decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality

Let $f(x)$ be a decreasing function defined over the interval $[0,a]$, with $f(0)=b$. The first derivative of $f(x)$, which is negative, is such that $f^\prime(x) > g(x)$, or equivalently $|f^\prime(x)| < |g(x)|$, where $g(x)=c_1x+c_2$.

For $x_2 >x_1$, can we say something like $f(x_1) > k f(x_2)$ (or $f(x_1) < k f(x_2)$ for some $k$ ? if yes, how to determine $k$ ? what if we set $c_2=0$ ?

Comment: I think the title and tags are misleading. I thought at first you were asking if a decreasing function has bounded variation (it does)

Comment: @par please feel free to edit the question.

Comment: @din Based on your comment below, it sounds like you're trying to find values of $k$ that work given fixed $x_1$ and $x_2$. Is that the case? By the way, three of the tags should be deleted: functional-analysis (it's not analysis of functions), functions (only for elementary questions in the spirit of elementary set theory), and bounded-variation (which usually concerns oscillating and discontinuous functions). You could add the inequality tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are evidently using "decreasing" is a strict sense, yes, you can with $k = 1$. This is the definition of "decreasing". For any value of $k$ other than $1$, it is false for at least one such function $f$.

If $f$ is any such function, and $d$ is any constant, then $f(x) + d$ also satisfies the same condition. In particular, there is such a function $f$ that is strictly positive on $[0,a]$. And there is another where $f$ is strictly negative. Also note that since $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous.

If $k > 1$ and $f$ is positive, then for $x_1$ sufficiently close to $x_2$, $$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| < (k - 1)f(x_2)$$
by continuity. This implies that $f(x_1) < kf(x_2)$.

If $k < 1$ and $f$ is negative, then for $x_1$ sufficiently close to $x_2$, $$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| < (1- k)|f(x_2)| = (k - 1)f(x_2)$$
by continuity. Which again implies that $f(x_1) < kf(x_2)$.

Comment: But you are assuming $x_1$ sufficiently close to $x_2$, which is a very particular case..

Comment: All you have required is that $x_2 > x_1$, There is no restriction mentioned that eliminates values of $x_1$ that are close to $x_2$. I have shown that the only value of $k$ that works for *every* $f, x_1, x_2$ that satisfies the given conditions is the trivial $k = 1$. For particular $f, x_1$ and $x_2$, then obviously other values of $k$ would work, but what values they are would depend on the function and two values of $x$, which was not given in your problem.